# spring-amqp onMessage() method not processing next message when previous message processing is in progress

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using MessageListener to read messages from the specified queue and want to perform processing once i got message on queue.

Here is my code

```
@Bean
public MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer()
{
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    messageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    messageListenerContainer.setQueueNames("queue");
    messageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(vceListener());
    return messageListenerContainer;
}

 @Bean
public VListener vceListener()
{
    return new VListener();
}

@Component
public class VListener implements MessageListener
{
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message)
    {
      //start process 
    }
}
```

My processing time is more for one message and when one message process is going on I cant process another message which is coming on the queue.

so, cant I process multiple messages in parallel

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
messageListenerContainer.setConcurrentConsumers(5);
```

(or whatever concurrency you need).

See [the documentation for other container properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#containerAttributes).